# Unexpected token in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This site](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/) was working fine but suddenly errors have appeared.

Unexpected token ( - what does this mean? Looks correct to me, and has been working fine for many months.

```
<script>
    function (){      <--"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" here
        $(".message").focus(function() {
            $("#bubble").fadeOut();
        }).blur(function() {
            $("#bubble").fadeIn();
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: where is the function name? Without that, why will the browser call the fn ?

Comment: Name of function is missing.

Comment: She wants an IIFE, so I think the missing function name was on purpose.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't specified a function name...

I.e.:

```
function functionname() { ...}
```

which you can later call as `functionname();`

I guess you're trying to use `(function () { ... })();` (IIFE)

Comment: Judging by the closing `})();` however, he wants an IIFE so he's missing a `(` at the start.

Comment: @Matt Updated answer to include IIFE

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to add a opening bracket before `function(`:

```
(function (){
    $(".message").focus(function() {
    $("#bubble").fadeOut();
   }).blur(function() {
    $("#bubble").fadeIn();
   });
})();
```

For everybody who might think: *"But no, she simply forgot the functioname!!111eleven"*:

I'm assuming that she wants to use [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (IIFE), a JavaScript design pattern.